# Async/await in MVC - Why is releasing thread during long-running operation important

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asynchronous

I have encountered a lot of questions about benefits of async/await in MVC. They mention it is important not to block the request thread so the worker thread could service different requests in the mean time. Till here it is ok and easily understandable.

- However I dont understand what is the difference between a normal and
  a request/worker thread? Is there such a big difference between the
  two so that releasing worker thread and creating normal thread is so
  beneficial?
- Why is the number of request thread limited compared to regular
  threads?
- Is the request thread much more memory intensive?

Feel free to point me to some article explain the reasons in more details.

Comment: This should explain it: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However I dont understand what is the difference between a normal and a request/worker thread?

That's not the point of releasing the thread. The point of releasing the thread is that there's one fewer thread needed to handle that request load. This in turn means that your service can handle higher load (and more quickly changing loads).

Using `async`/`await` enables your website to scale further (and more quickly). If your backend is also scalable (e.g., a cloud data store), then making your web tier scalable allows your system as a whole to scale further (and faster).

I describe this more (and with pictures!) in my [intro to async ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx) article.